# Calling an Arraylist method and calling it on if statement condition

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

So I was asked to do these task:
Write an executable console application GuessingGame where a player tries to guess a
number between 1 and 20. At the start of each game, GuessingGame instantiates a Player
object which will be used to store the game scores for a given player. The player’s name is
assigned from user input. The program then generates a random number between 1 and 20
and asks the player to guess the number. When the player enters a number, the program tells
the player whether the number is too high or too low. The player should keep entering guess
numbers until the correct number is entered.
The score is computed as follow:

> score = (20 – the number of guesses).

Each player is asked to play the game five times, so five scores are stored for each player.
The application should then display the average and best score for the player.

I got the game working although I am stuck on the if statement. I tried calling the getScore method from Player class but I am getting operand errors. here is my GuessingGame code:

```
public class GuessingGame
{
public static void main (String [] args)
throws IOException
{

    String name;
    final int numberOfGuess = 5;

    //Create Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Player[] player1 = new Player[numberOfGuess];

    //Ask user for name
    System.out.printf("\n Enter Player Name:");
    name = input.nextLine();

    PrintStream fout = new PrintStream(new File("PlayerData.txt"));
    for (int index = 0; index < player1.length ; index++)
    {
        int playerId = index + 1;
        player1[index] = new Player(name); // reference to Student object
        player1[index].setName(name);


        //Ask user for number input
        System.out.println("Please pic a number between 1 - 20");
        player1[index].setScore(Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()));
        Random rand = new Random();
        int answer = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
        System.out.println(answer);
        System.out.println(player1[index].getScores());

        if(answer >= player1[index].getScores())
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
        }


    }
    fout.println( "" + player1[1].getName() );
    for (int index = 0; index < player1.length ; index++)
        {
            int playerId = index + 1;
            fout.println( "" + player1[index].getScores() );

            }

}

}`
```

And here is my Player class:

```
//Class declaration of Player class
public class Player
{
   /*--------------- Data Fields ---------------------------------------
   Attributes of the class
   */
   private String name;
   private int playerId;
   private int bestScore;
   private static int numberOfPlayers = 0;
   private ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   /* -------------- CONSTRUCTOR --------------------------------------
   */
   public Player(String name)
   {
       this.name = name;
       numberOfPlayers++;
       playerId = numberOfPlayers;

   }

   //Create set method for setName
   public void setName(String name)
   {
       this.name = name;
   }
   //Create set method for setScores
   public void setScore(int score)
   {
       scores.add(score);
   }
   //Create get method for getScores
   public ArrayList<Integer> getScores()
   {
       return scores;
   }


}
```

I did not put the rest of the methods as they are not the issue. 
Did I set the methods incorrectly ? If so how do I get around this issue ?

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>='
   if(answer >= player1[index].getScores())first type:  int
  second type: ArrayList<Integer>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This attempts to compare an `int` to an `ArrayList<Integer>`:

```
if (answer >= player1[index].getScores())
```

Perhaps you want to compare the `int` to the size of the `ArrayList`:

```
if (answer >= player1[index].getScores().size())
```

or to compare the `int` to some element of the `ArrayList`:

```
if (answer >= player1[index].getScores().get(someIndex))
```

It's not clear from your question what the desired logic is.

Comment: That's a nice catch :)

Comment: I want to be able to compare what I have in stored in getScore to the generated random number to be able to show the using that his guess was either low or high

Comment: @AnthonyGalpo Can you be more accurate? What exactly do you want to compare `answer` to? Do you want to find if `answer` is equal to any of the Integers in the ArrayList returned by `getScores()`, or do you want something else?

Comment: Each time the user enters a guess I have to compare 'answer' to the score that was taken from the user which is stored on the 'getScore()'.

Comment: @AnthonyGalpo Which element of getScore() do you wish to compare to? The first? The last?

Comment: Well first guess would be with the first element and second guess with the second element and so on.

Comment: @AnthonyGalpo But which one of them do you wish to compare `answer` to?

Comment: @Eran Sorry for all the trouble. I think I have figured it out. if(answer >= player1[index].getScores().get(0)). Seems to work now.